# Read a plain text file inside project file path but get error file not found

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am developing a node.js + typescript project.  Here is my project structure:

```
myapp/
  data.txt
  src/
    helpers/
     worker.ts
```

So, `myapp` is the project root, under it there is an `src/` directory and a `data.txt` file, under `src` there is a `helpers/` directory, and my `worker.ts` is under it.

The `data.txt` is a plain text.

`worker.ts` code would like to read the content of that `data.txt` file. This is the code I tried in `worker.ts`:

```
import fs from "fs/promises";

async function readData() {
  const data = await fs.readFile("../../data.txt", "utf-8");
  ...
}
```

However, when I run it I get error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../data.txt'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '../../data.txt'
```

Why is that? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The url passed to readFile is relative to `process.cwd()` not `__dirname`.

It is recommended that you use absolute paths. The core module `path` would give you the ability to build the correct URL for multiple platforms using something like

```
const path = require('path')
const uri = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'data.txt')

const data = fs.readFileSync(uri, 'utf-8')
```